# Codificación y Compilación en Java

Tags: java, utf-8, codificación, compilar

Estoy intentando programar en java, pero al ejecutar cualquier archivo .java me falla la codificación, salen mal las tildes y símbolos, la ñ... Está todo en UTF-8. He probado a ejecutar con javac y con javac -encoding utf8, y sigue dando errores, no se compila ni se hace el archivo .class

En geany el código es:

```
public class Colores { // Clase principal
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("\033[33m mandarina");
    System.out.print("\033[32m hierba");
    System.out.print("\033[31m tomate");
    System.out.print("\033[37m sábanas");
    System.out.print("\033[36m cielo");
    System.out.print("\033[35m nazareno");
    System.out.print("\033[34m mar");
  }
}
```

Este ejercicio al menos si lo compila, y al ejecutar me sale [33m mandarina[32m hierba[31m tomate[37m sÃ¡banas[36m cielo[35m nazareno[34m mar

Ahora al intentar compilar este :

```
public class Ejercicio1Tema1 { // Clase principal
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Sergio García");
  }
}
```

Al compilar y ejecutar este me sale: "Sergio GarcÃ­a" en vez de "Sergio García"

No se si será la CMD pero también he ejecutado esos archivos java con la Git Bash y salen los mismos símbolos.

Comment: No publiques fotos, copia el texto. Imposible trabajar mirando imagenes.

Comment: Listo. Ya lo he cambiado.

Comment: Cuando se guarde el bloc de notas, asegúrate de que la codificación sea ANSI, no UTF-8.
Así ya funcionaran los acentos.

Answer (score 0):

He probado tu código de forma exacta en Intell IJ y NetBeans y funciona de forma correcta, la codificación UTF-8 es perfecta, el problema lo estarás teniendo con el CMD. 
Te recomendaría que antes de escribir un post pruebes a ejecutar el código en IDE, dejo foto de verificación.
Espero ayudarte, un saludo!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vale gracias! El problema también, es que nos obligan a estudiar con una consola, y yo estoy usando Git Bash en windows, cual podría usar en windows? Que me sirva también para usar Git y GitHub aparte de la Git Bash esta que me está dando esos problemas. Gracias!

Comment: Bueno, a mi también me funciona, tanto desde Netbeans como en linea de comandos, pero estoy en Linux. Debe ser problema de ambiente en Windows.